# A subset of a finite interval is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Can you help me out to prove this?

Let $[a,b]$ be a finite interval in $\mathbb{R}$ and $E \subset [a,b]$. Prove that if $m^*(E) + m^*([a,b]\setminus E) = b - a$, then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I tried approximating $[a,b]$ through $G_{\delta}$ sets or $F_{\delta}$, but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Since there are several (equivalent) definitions of Lebesgue measurability, one of which seems to be what you're trying trying to prove, you should include the specific definition of "Lebesgue measurable" that you're suppose to use. By the way, does "finite interval" mean an interval of nonzero finite length? If so, then such an interval can also be non-compact, such as $(a,b]$ or $(a,b)$ or $[a,b).$ If you specifically want the interval to have the form $[a,b]$ with $a<b,$ then you should use a phrase that is more specific than "finite interval".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F=[a,b]\setminus E$. There exist $G_{\delta}$ sets $G_E\supset E$ and $G_F\supset F$ s.t. $m(G_E)=m^{*}(E)$ and $m(G_F)=m^{*}(F)$. Then
\begin{align}
m(G_E\cup G_F)&\le m(G_E)+m(G_F)=m^{*}(E)+m^{*}(F) \\
&=m(E\cup F)\le m(G_E\cup G_F),
\end{align}
which implies that $m(G_E\cap G_F)=0$. Therefore, $E$ is measurable because
$$
E=(([0,1])\setminus G_F)\cup(E\cap G_F)
$$
and $E\cap G_F\subset G_E\cap G_F$ is a null set.